# How to jump to type definition in Emacs + merlin

Tags: emacs, ocaml, keyboard-shortcuts, merlin

Is there a way to jump to the type definition of the type of the value under the current cursor? For example if we have the following code:

```
type weekday = Mon | Tue | Wed | Thu | Fri | Sat | Sun

let () = Mon(* cursor here *)
```

when you have merlin setup correctly in emacs and hitting `C-c C-t`, in the minibuffer merlin will show the type of `Mon` as `type weekday = ..`. Is there a way to jump to the type definition of `type weekday` after showing the type?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I know you can use Atl-x merlin-locate-type and then use C-c & to jump back.